# How to get the current day orders through REST API?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, api, rest-api

I am getting the initial 10 records by the following step --

```
oauth = OAuth(client_key=CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET, resource_owner_key=TOKEN, resource_owner_secret=SECRET)
h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url='0.0.0.0/api/rest/orders', headers=h, auth=oauth)
```

but I want the present day all records, and this is done in Python.

Answer (score 1):

10 is the default limit result. To get the rest of the results either raise the limit by adding `limit=100` for example to the parameters or `page=2` for the next 10.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to change the limit to a higher amount and while looping, if the last item you retrieved is still in today's date then get the next page.

I updated this to code that should work, but I am unable to test it.  Make sure you note the "from" date has a %20 between the date and time:

```
oauth = OAuth(client_key=CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
resource_owner_key=TOKEN, resource_owner_secret=SECRET)
h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url='0.0.0.0/api/rest/orders?filter[0][attribute]=created_at&filter[0][from][0]=2015-10-29%2000:00:00', headers=h, auth=oauth)
```

Comment: THANKS.... worked in a single shot ... but am wondering is there any way in which we can pass the current date. By this we can get the record of a specific day rather than looping and then checking the records.

Comment: Nilay, see the edited version of the answer above.  I cannot test, but it should be on the right path.  Let me know if you have issues with it.  I will test if time permits.

Comment: hey thanks for the help, but its not working.

error :: ` ValueError: Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string. Found invalid characters: set([u'[', u':', u']']) in the string: 'filter[0][attribute]=created_at&filter[0][from][0]=2015-10-29%2000:00:00'. Please ensure the request/response body is x-www-form-urlencoded.`

and a more thing if it works fine then will it return only 10 records or the complete records? if it is 10 records then do i have to raise the limits to get all records ?

Comment: Nilay, 
/api/rest/orders?filter[0][attribute]=created_at&filter[0][from][0]=2015-02-13%2000:00:00  works fine for me, tested on EE 1.14.1.   Make sure, if you are copying and pasting that you don't have a strange single quote character.     If you don't get them all, set an artificially high limit that's more than you should receive in a day.